# How to get required json output from complex nested json format.?

Tags: json, python-3.x, string

My original file is in CSV format which I have converted to python JSON array to JSON Sring.
jsonfile

```
<class 'list'>
<class 'dict'>

[
  {
    "key": "timestamp",
    "source": "eia007",
    "turnover": "65million",
    "url": "abc.com",
    "record": "",
    "loc.reg": "nord000",
    "loc.count": "abs39i5",
    "loc.town": "cold54",
    "co.gdp": "nscrt77",
    "co.pop.min": "min50",
    "co.pop.max": "max75",
    "co.rev": "",
    "chain.system": "5t5t5",
    "chain.type": "765ef",
    "chain.strat": "",
    
   }
]
```

I would like to get the output as below:

```
{
 "timestamp001": {
 "key": "timestamp001",
 "phNo": "ner007",
 "turnover": "65million",
 "url": "abc.com",
 "record": "",
 "loc": {
    "reg": "nord000",
    "count": "abs39i5",
    "town": "cold54"
   },
 "co": {
    "form": "nscrt77",
    "pop": {
        "min": "min50",
        "max": "max75"
         },
        "rev: ""
    },
  "chain":{
           "system": "5t5t5",
           "type": "765ef",
           "strat": ""
          }
     ...
      }
...
  }
]
```

I have tried different options; tried to enumerate, but cannot get the required output. Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this to create the nested dict:

```
import json

def unflatten(somedict):
    unflattened = {}

    for key, value in somedict.items():
        splitkey = key.split(".")
        print(f"doing {key} {value} {splitkey}")

        # subdict is the dict that goes deeper in the nested structure
        subdict = unflattened

        for subkey in splitkey[:-1]:

            # if this is the first time we see this key, add it
            if subkey not in subdict:
                subdict[subkey] = {}

            # shift the subdict a level deeper
            subdict = subdict[subkey]

        # add the value
        subdict[splitkey[-1]] = value

    return unflattened


data = {
    "key": "timestamp",
    "source": "eia007",
    "turnover": "65million",
    "url": "abc.com",
    "record": "",
    "loc.reg": "nord000",
    "loc.count": "abs39i5",
    "loc.town": "cold54",
    "co.gdp": "nscrt77",
    "co.pop.min": "min50",
    "co.pop.max": "max75",
    "co.rev": "",
    "chain.system": "5t5t5",
    "chain.type": "765ef",
    "chain.strat": "",
}

unflattened = unflatten(data)
print(json.dumps(unflattened, indent=4))
```

Which produces:

```
{
    "key": "timestamp",
    "source": "eia007",
    "turnover": "65million",
    "url": "abc.com",
    "record": "",
    "loc": {
        "reg": "nord000",
        "count": "abs39i5",
        "town": "cold54"
    },
    "co": {
        "gdp": "nscrt77",
        "pop": {
            "min": "min50",
            "max": "max75"
        },
        "rev": ""
    },
    "chain": {
        "system": "5t5t5",
        "type": "765ef",
        "strat": ""
    }
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you. This is working on a smaller subset of data; if I add more data, throws TypeError: ('str' object does not support item assignment).because of strings immutability I suppose?

Comment: No you probably have a dict like this `{"a": "val", "a.b": "val"}` I'm guessing, so the nested structure is ambiguos: the key `a` is added, with a value that is a string, but then `a.b` is parsed and the program tries to add a subkey `b` (because `a` does exist at this point) but it fails because `unflattened['a']` is a string and not a dict. You need to decide how to deal with a case like this explicitly.